# MongoDB Stitch REST API - Payload Signature Verification

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, mongodb-stitch

I am working on a SANDBOX Cluster & a new app created by me in MongoDB Stitch.

I need to understand "Payload Signature Verification" in MongoDB Stitch App. Lets say, I need to make a REST GET API, which will fetch me a list of products, but this API call must be authenticated ie. only registered/authenticated users will be able to make this call. MongoDB Stitch suggests below to do that:

https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/webhook-requests-and-responses/#webhook-verify-payload-signature

But, i need to understand:

[image: image1]

(1) Where to add this BODY & SECRET ? As per my knowledge, it must be kept in the stitch app, as you must not expose any of your secret keys in client side javascript.

(2) { "message":"MESSAGE" } is this configurable? if yes, what value should we add here?

[image: image2]

This function must be coded in MongoDB Stitch App. That is clear. This function returns "hash" based on the "body" & "secret" you pass in earlier step.

And now, you must pass this hash in your API Request:

[image: image3]

Now, the question is:

You can easily see any request which is being passed to server in developer tools, anybody can easily copy it & pass it same through POSTMAN. So:

-> How do i secure my requests? (FYI: I have also added "RULES", saying this request must execute only if the domain name contains lets say, www.mysite.com. But i am able to execute the request successfully from localhost.)

-> If, anybody can copy & paste my request in POSTMAN & run it. SO, what is the use of generating that HASH ?

-> How do i keep my request(s) tokens alive/valid for limited period of time, lets say request is valid only for next 5 minutes ? (i mean how do i do this in Stitch APP ? Where is that Option ?)

-> How do i get the refresh token ? & even if i get it somehow, how do i re-pass it to the request ?

All such queries are UN_ANSWERED in MongoDB Stich Documentation : https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/

Basically i want to understand the full life-cycle of any GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE request of MongoDB Stitch App / Stitch REST APIs.

If anybody have used MongoDB Stich, please explain me.

Comment: I am also looking to understand the same. Were you able to figure it out ?

Comment: Could you clarify your use case more please ? i.e. `I need to make a REST GET API` part. Are you intending to open the Stitch HTTP API to users, or are you intending to create your own server that talks to Stitch HTTP API and then open your server to users ?

Comment: I have the exact same question as "You can easily see any request which is being passed to server in developer tools, anybody can easily copy it & pass it same through POSTMAN. How do i secure my requests?". Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your specific use-case, though I also had issues with creating an Authenticated HTTP REST API. My idea was: I already have all security rules and schemas defined in Stitch, now I want to access the data over HTTP still using the logic defined in Stitch and not rewriting everything.

I wasn't able to create such API with Stitch functions and Webhooks, though I created an API server in (literally) 1 hour with NodeJS [Koa](https://koajs.com) (express or any other framework would do) and [Stitch server SDK](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch-sdks/js-server/4/index.html):

```js
// app.js
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = module.exports = new Koa()

const auth = require('./auth')
const router = require('./router')

app.use(auth())
app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

// listen
if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000)
}
```

```js
// auth.js
const { loginWithApiKey } = require('./stitch')

function auth () {
  return async function auth (ctx, next) {
    const apiKey = ctx.query.api_key

    try {
      await loginWithApiKey(apiKey)
    } catch (e) {
      ctx.throw(401, 'Not Authorized')
    }

    await next()
  }
}

module.exports = auth
```

```js
// router.js
const router = require('koa-router')()
const { BSON } = require('mongodb-stitch-server-sdk')

const { db } = require('./stitch')

router.get('/', async (ctx) => {
  ctx.body = { message: 'Nothing to see, but you\'re good!' }
})

const COLLECTIONS_WHITELIST = [
  'activities',
  'expenses',
  'projects',
  'resources'
]

// List
router.get('/:collection', async (ctx) => {
  const collection = ctx.params.collection

  isValidCollection(ctx, collection)

  ctx.body = await db
    .collection(collection)
    .find()
    .toArray()
})

function isValidCollection (ctx, collection) {
  // check if the collection is allowed in the API
  if (!COLLECTIONS_WHITELIST.includes(collection)) {
    ctx.throw(404, `Unknown API entity ${collection}`)
  }
}

module.exports = router
```

I hope it helps